# SSRS Drill Through Action When Value Is 0

Tags: visual-studio-2012, matrix, ssrs-2012, zero, drillthrough

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for my current project.

I currently have a matrix that has the fields Employee, Count(Files)and Avg(AgeFiles) which is how long they are open/have been open.

Basically, right now I have 7 employees. When I pull in my data, some of them have a 0 in the Count(Files) box.

[image]

Right now I have a drillthrough action that whenyou click on a particular box, it will take you to another matrix with a lot more information about those particular files. Say you click on the 4, it will bring up only those 4 files.

What I wanted to know is since that one employee has a 0, is there a way that I can make it so that if the box is 0, it will ignore the drill through because there are no files to go to.

I don't how much this will affect answer, but this is how I currently have Matrix setup and the matrix is populated based on the data pulled in.

Is there any way to stop the drill throughs on the 0 values?

[image]

Comment: I think the only way to get the conditional drillthrough is using a different report to show the matrix, i.e you will have two reports one for summary data, another to show the matrix with detail data. If you are ok with that I'll post an answer.

Comment: Yeah, whatever works I'm willing to try.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IIF(Count(Files) > 0, "DrillThroughName", nothing)
```